# dlib: extract_histogram_descriptors inside extract_highdim_face_lbp_descriptors returns vector with zeros

Tags: dlib

I'm trying to extract this features, but it is returning a vector with all zeros. I called the function dlib::extract_highdim_face_lbp_descriptors and followed the code and it seems that is extract_histogram_descriptors is what it is returning zeros.

So I hope anyone can help, it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

This are the important lines of my code:
                std::vector features;

```
            dlib::array2d<unsigned char> grayFace;
            dlib::assign_image(grayFace, face);

            dlib::extract_highdim_face_lbp_descriptors<dlib::array2d<unsigned char>, double>(grayFace, shape, features);
```

face is an array2D containing the recognized face, shape is of type dlib::full_object_detection.
I have also check that grayFace and shape are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I could solve this problem, I post the answer in case someone has the same problem.
The thing is that as first argument, dlib::extract_highdim_face_lbp_descriptors expects the hole frame image, not just the found face which is what I was given to it.